# Proper Thymeleaf syntex within a th:replace tag

Tags: spring, syntax, thymeleaf

I have this block of code Thymeleaf calls the Spring context and pulls in the user id.

```
 <li {#ctx.httpSession} >
                      <span th:object="${session.user}"> </span>
                      <span><p>Surname: <span th:text="*{user.id}">Pepper</span></p></span>
```

I would like to place it into a existing th:replace listed item. Basically i need to get the static 2 replaced with a current session userid inside the url I have  tried numerous options, and cant seem to find a solution online.

```
This is one of my attempts
<li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" {#ctx.httpSession}, th:object="${session.user}"  th:replace="::menuItem ( '/users/'+*{user.id}+'/coworkers/find','coworkers','find coworkers','search','Find coworkers')"><span>Find Coworkers</span>
                  </li>
This is the orginial 
<li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"  th:replace="::menuItem ( '/users/2/coworkers/find','coworkers','find coworkers','search','Find coworkers')">
```

I am a Thymeleaf novice so any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Have tried {***{user.id}**}

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "user.id" (template: "fragments/layout" - line 65, col 106)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
th:replace="::menuItem(*{'/users/' + user.id + '/coworkers/find'}, 'coworkers', 'find coworkers', 'search', 'Find coworkers')"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried 
`code`
 <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" {#ctx.httpSession}, th:object="${session.user}" th:replace="::menuItem(*{'/users/' + user.id + '/coworkers/find'}, 'coworkers', 'find coworkers', 'search', 'Find coworkers')">
`code`   
As you said but am receiving the same error. I am 90% sure I am not typing the thymeleaf tags properly it has been very difficult to find some information even in the documentation.

Comment: What is `{#ctx.httpSession},` and why do you have it in a tag like that? It doesn't look like valid html.

Comment: It is something that I do not need, completely useless.  Comes from my misunderstanding of how the template code works.
This code
<span th:object="${session.user}"> </span>
                  <span><p>Surname: <span th:text="*{user.id}">id</span></p></span>
Works without it.

Comment: This works sort of. But the output is "/users/null/coworkers/find"
I am thinking the th:replace is causing the id to come up as null.  
`code`
<li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:object="${session.user}" th:replace="::menuItem ('/','home','home page','home', '/users/'+*{id}+'/coworkers/find')">
`code`

Comment: Have you defined a `th:object`? That's what `*{...}` (asterisk instead of dollar sign) expressions are for.  What is your model object named?

Comment: Yes the th:object="${session.user}" it works on other pages that I tested just not within the layout.html page.